# How to check if AXIOS POST request is sent?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, async-await, axios, react-hooks

[image: Picture of Code]

I can't seem to figure out why my `console.log();` isn't going off. It seems that everything after the `await axios.post();` method doesn't go off? Even my `handleClearData();` function isn't going off.

I'm using React with Axios for my contact form to send data to a NodeJS server to then email the data to my email.

Could anyone please explain to me or point me in the right direction on solving this problem? Also, the `console.log(res);` obviously doesn't return or log anything as well.

Thanks a ton!

**UPDATED:**

Here's more info. I even took out my function thinking it may have been the problem. It wasn't...

[image: Here's more info!]

**SECOND UPDATE:**

Another update!

[image: More info!]

Comment: could be some error in your `handleClearData` function. Can you post more code please. Are you using classes? console output?

Comment: also, by opening your chrome devtools and going to networks tab, you can see all XHR requests being sent.

Comment: @YasserZubair I'm not using classes; I'm using state hooks and function based components. As for the network tab, I just checked it and did get a (failed).

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to put the console log under `handleClearData();` within the (first) try block.

Comment: @Brain Swisher I managed to fix it! =) the problem was that in my backend, it was waiting for a response, and I didn't add the `res.end()` method after it sent my info to said email. Thanks tho!

Answer (score 0):

[image]

I managed to fix it because `await` method was waiting for a response from the server. So, on my backend I put this simple line of code, `res.send()` which then allowed the `await` function to get out of its infinite loop; therefore, executing the rest of the code that came after it.

Thanks to all that tried to help me! =)

**&& happy coding!**